# Adjust existing Tensorflow Graphs (VGG)

Tags: tensorflow, vgg-net

I want to use the VGG converted tensorflow model from Ryan.

https://github.com/ry/tensorflow-vgg16

Now I want to adjust the layers and add another layer or change the fully connected layers. But I don't know how to get the single layers/weights out of the `graphDef` or how to adjust the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't adjust a graph, but there are probably ways to get what you want accomplished.

Long answer: TensorFlow Graph objects are structurally immutable. You can modify some aspects of them (e.g., the shape of a tensor flowing into a node), but you can't remove a node or add a node between two existing nodes. However, there are a couple ways to get the same effect:

1. If your changes are limited to additions *only*, then there's no problem with doing this. For instance, if you wanted to add a layer on the end of a network, go for it. Likewise, you can "replace" the last layer by simply adding a new layer which takes the second-to-last layer as input and just ignoring the existing last layer. When you run the graph, if you never ask for the output of the original last layer, TensorFlow will never compute it.
2. If you need to do modifications, one way is to slowly build up a copy of the graph node by node. So read in the original graph definition, then build your own new graph by iterating over the original and adding similar nodes to your new copy. This is somewhat tedious and can be error-prone. Moreover...
3. ...You might not need to "adjust" the graph at all. If you want something similar to that VGG-16 implementation, you can just work off the [python code](https://github.com/ry/tensorflow-vgg16/blob/master/vgg16.py) directly. Don't like the width of fc6? Just edit the code that generates it.

This brings us to the real issue, though. If your goal is to modify the network **and** be able to re-use the weights, then 2. and 3. aren't going to work. Realistically, this isn't possible in a lot of cases. For instance, if I wanted to add or remove a layer in the middle of VGG-16 (say, adding another convolutional layer), the pre-trained weights are no longer valid. You might be able to salvage any pre-trained weights which are upstream of your changes, but everything downstream will basically be wrong. You'll need to retrain the network anyways. (Maybe you can use the pre-trained networks as initialization, but you'll still need to retrain.) Even if you're just adding to the network (as in 1.), you'll still need to train the network.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I have recreated the graph and then loaded every single weight by getting the value of the graph definition.

This was done by graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/...') where ... is the name of the weight

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/tool_developers/index.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.